# Start a jar file like service in linux

Tags: java, linux, shell, jar, executable-jar

I want to start and stop my jar file as follows

`service myService start`

`service myService stop`

my current jar file running as follows

```
cd /home/alex/IdeaProjects/myService
java -jar target/myService-SNAPSHOT-1.jar server config.yml
```

What should I do?

Comment: Implement a wrapper service. A little search will show up some 3rd party implementation you could use.

Comment: Dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203483/run-a-java-application-as-a-service-on-linux

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need a Service Wrapper to run the Jar file.

There are examples and instructions for init.d [here.](http://www.jcgonzalez.com/linux-java-service-wrapper-example) or for systemd (ubuntu 16+) [here](http://www.jcgonzalez.com/ubuntu-16-java-service-wrapper-example)

Comment: Just an info for people who are on Ubuntu 16+. This doesn't work with Ubuntu 16+. You will get 'Failed to start MyService.service: Unit MyService.service not found'

Comment: systemd version works awesome :D

Answer (score 6):

I prefer a light weight, free, bash script rather than a more elaborate system that requires licensing.

http://gustavostraube.wordpress.com/2009/11/05/writing-an-init-script-for-a-java-application/

[Running jar as a Linux service - init.d script gets stuck starting app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19248365/running-jar-as-a-linux-service-init-d-script-gets-stuck-starting-app)

https://askubuntu.com/questions/99232/how-to-make-a-jar-file-run-on-startup-and-when-you-log-out

Comment: Your links are very helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you want to try the DIY way, you can place a startup script in your /etc/init.d directory as said here.

http://www.ghacks.net/2009/04/04/get-to-know-linux-the-etcinitd-directory/

However, to implement a clean `yourScript stop` command, I would recommend that you split your functionality into a launcher and a daemon, and make your launcher able to start or communicate with your existing daemon in order to send orders to it.  Then your startup script would only invoke your launcher, which in its turn would start a new daemon, or send orders to the existing one.

Comment: Request: Could you plz post a small example of launcher and daemon(for this particular case) Or  add link to some effective tutorial.
Thanks.

Comment: I am afraid I have nothing at hand.  Your best shot is to leave a port open in your service for administration purposes just as application servers do, and then write a simple 30-40 lines program (your launcher) that sends orders to that port.  Then your service would have a thread listening on that port, processing the restart or stop orders

Comment: Sime time ago I was solving similar task I documented https://jaksky.wordpress.com/2013/11/03/java-application-as-a-linux-service/