# Does Commons-Daemon exist to make your executable JAR a service?

Tags: java, linux, service, apache-commons, apache-commons-daemon

Say I have an executable JAR called `myapp.jar`. Does [Apache Commons-Daemon](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/) exist so that I could then write a `/etc/init.d/myapp` service script (for starting/stopping a `myapp` service), and then treat `myapp` like a regular Linux service:

```
service myapp stop
service myapp start
service myapp restart
```

Or does it do something else?

Comment: Did you read the documentation? They probably mention something about the intended use.

Comment: Thanks @Kayaman, but did **you** read the documentation?!? The only "documentation" they have (this is an old project) is the link that I posted above, which does not make it very clear what the intended use is ;-)

Comment: Why don't you look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21546278/start-a-jar-file-like-service-in-linux

Comment: To all those who voted to close this: you never even took the time to read this question. My question clearly is *not* "How do I get a JAR to run like a service on Linux", may question was "What are the use cases for Commons-Daemon." Congrats on closing a perfect valid, never-before-answered question. In fact, I'm just going to wait a day or two and ask it again, in a slightly different format. Once it gets answered, I'll update this question with a link to the answer on that 2nd question to help future-comers out.

Comment: Actually I found [this article](http://www.neilson.co.za/creating-a-java-daemon-system-service-for-debian-using-apache-commons-jsvc/) which exhibits the use cases for Apache Commons Daemon beautifully.