# is possible run spring boot application on backend?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have my spring boot application, I normally work with wars that I deploy on tomcat, but I want to try this way a little bit more.

My problem is that when I deploy it in a server, and I do

```
java -jar target/myproject.jar
```

Works pretty fine, but after a time without use, the shell gets disconnected and soon after it (I believe because the shell) the process stops.

Any idea how to deal with this?

I am using Debian.

Thanks.

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21546422/1291150 ... you can write some script around the JAR and launch it as a service.

Comment: I dont understand the answer ... the service is an .sh file? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203483/run-a-java-application-as-a-service-on-linux/21283530#21283530

Comment: nevermind, I figured out, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, create a .sh file and set it on `/etc/init.d/YOURFILE.sh` with the info of this post

[Run a Java Application as a Service on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203483/run-a-java-application-as-a-service-on-linux/21283530#21283530)

Later just make a `/etc/init.d/YOURFILE.sh` start and thats it..